# Find $F'(x)$ when $F(x)= \int_a^{x^2}f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis

Find $F'(x)$ when $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continous and $F(x)= \int_a^{x^2}f(t)dt$.

The hint given is to use the chain rule but I cannot see how chain rule can be applied in this case.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If it was $\int_a^x f(t)dt$, do you know how to do the problem? If you do, then think of $x^2$ as a function of $x$. In other words if you write $y(x)=x^2$, then $F(x)=F(y(x))$. Now differentiate in $x$ and use the chain rule, plugging the definition of $y$ back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule: You should obtain

$$F'(x) = f(x^2) 2x.$$

To see it better. Denote by $y(x) = x^2$, a function of $x$. Then
$$\frac{d}{dx} F(y(x)) = F'(y(x)) y'(x) = F'(x^2) 2x = f(x^2) 2x.$$

Observe that the chain-rule is used in the first step above, and the fundamental theorem of caculus is used in the last step above.

Answer (score 1):

Hint part 2: Let $g(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$.  What is $g'(x)$?  Can you write an expression for $F$ in terms of $g$?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the more general $d \left(\int_a^b f(t) \, dt \right) = f(b) \, db - f(a) \, da$ to find $$d\int_a^{x^2} f(t) \, dt = f(x^2) d(x^2) = 2xf(x^2) \, dx$$ if $a$ is constant. this gives you $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x^2} f(t) \, dt  = 2xf(x^2).$